# Output the number of each RGB value of an mask image using pillow?

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am trying to extract the number of each RGB value from the sample photo like below using python pillow. But, the image is only processing the background color Green.

[image: sample image]

I have tried this script

```
i = Image.open(img_path, 'r')
r, g, b = i.getpixel((0, 0))
print("Red: {}, Green: {}, Blue: {}".format(r, g, b))
```

But the output is showing like this.

```
Red: 0, Green: 255, Blue: 0
```

the image  size is (2048, 1536) and its PNG.
How do I get value of red and blue pixels? I am new to this any kind of help is appreciate.

`

Comment: You want to print 3 million RGB triplets... why?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I needed to document pixel value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your unique RGB values by:

```
np.unique(np.array(i).reshape(-1,3),axis=0)
```

However, your image has more than simple green/blue/red points:

Unique sets of RGB in your image:

```
[[  0  42 255]
 [  0  44 255]
 [  0  46 193]
 ...
 [255  64  44]
 [255  64  63]
 [255  65  44]]
```

or:

```
print(["Red: {}, Green: {}, Blue: {}".format(r, g, b) for (r,g,b) in colors])

['Red: 0, Green: 42, Blue: 255', 
'Red: 0, Green: 44, Blue: 255', 
'Red: 0, Green: 46, Blue: 193', 
'Red: 0, Green: 46, Blue: 207', 
'Red: 0, Green: 47, Blue: 215', 
'Red: 0, Green: 50, Blue: 255', 
'Red: 0, Green: 53, Blue: 255', 
'Red: 0, Green: 83, Blue: 90', 
'Red: 0, Green: 94, Blue: 100', 
'Red: 1, Green: 45, Blue: 238',
...
]
```

Comment: Thank you. It still not working. The image I am showing is the sample image. Its not the real image I am processing. But it look exactly like that. The image is mask image or some sort of backgroud, foregorund separate image. I guess. I have no idea